# Postgresql update column with window function

Tags: postgresql, update, window-functions

Take a look on example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wN8A7pfuGos9KfLokFS3uy/0

It is possible to update `payment_line_tab` and `paid` column in efficient way?
I would like to set paid column to value:
0 - if is unpaid
1 - if is totally paid
2 - if is partially paid

As you can see in my example I have to incomes for $60 usd each so in total I have got $120 paid.

Because of that lines form `payment_line_tab`:

- with id 1,2,3,4 should be updated with value 1 as fully paid
- with id 5 should be updated with value 2 as partially paid
- with id 6 should be updated with 0 because line is not covered by any income

Payments should be ordered by Date ASC.

Now I have only covered case with 0 and 1 with that way (it is a part of trigger):

```
UPDATE payment_line_tab SET paid = 0 WHERE customer_id = 7

SELECT SUM(it.amount) INTO total_income FROM income_tab it WHERE customer_id = 7;

SELECT SUM(amount)
        INTO total_payment
        FROM payment_line_tab plt
        WHERE customer_id = 7;

UPDATE payment_line_tab
SET paid = 1
FROM (SELECT *, SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY payment_date, payment_line_id ASC) as total
      FROM payment_line_tab plt
      WHERE customer_id = 7) q
WHERE
    q.total <= total_income AND payment_line_tab.payment_line_id = q.payment_line_id;
```

Do you have any idea how to cover case with paid=2?

Maybe there is more efficient way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: The [balance timeline](https://dbfiddle.uk/6D8i7Cze) does not demonstrate, that "with id 5 should be updated with value 2 as **partially** paid" is not correct. For any date the balance is positive.

Comment: @Akina 5th payment line is partially paid. Total income is 120. First 4 payments totally gives 100. So 5th payment line to be 100% covered should have income about 125. So there is 5 missing (125 - 120 = 5). This is why 5h line is partially paid

Comment: 5th payment date is 2023-11-08 whereas total income at this moment is not 120 but only 60. I think that you must explain your "mechanic" more detailed.

Comment: @Akina now I understand your point of view. All incomes should be considered as sum of all together. Why? Even if you pay your bill after payment deadline but you will pay then you have marked your bill as paid.